# Assign string value in constructor

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot

**Task**:

I am trying to search solution for springboot application, where we would like to load CSV files, only in debug mode or development mode. Those CSV files contain test values, which represents data in correct format.

**Solution**:

According to [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) I choose the yaml configuration file, where I can say, that CSV file will be on some exact location (i.e.: classpath:/ ). Property looks like this:

```
spring
  profiles: development
  csv:
    first-csv: classpath:/first.csv
```

Then there is logic when we are reading sources. This logic will decide if we will call production data or mock data (csv files) according to mode (development or any other). In development mode we will try to read csv files, which should be placed in root folder for an application (as you can see above in yaml configuration.

**Problem**:

When I call constructor for class, where I need to know the position of .csv files, I don't know how to set those string values to local string values through constructor. My call looks like this:

```
@Configuration
class WhereWeDecideWhichWayToGo() {

  private final CSVProperties csvProperties;

  //Code for production solution - which works

  @Bean
  @Profile("development")
  public CreateMockData createMockData() {
    return new MockData(csvProperties.getMockCSV());
    }
}
```

Where CSVProperties is a class with only getters / setters for property from yaml configuration file. This class has annotation:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("csv")
```

And it works. The value from configuration file is read. During debug I can confirm, that csvProperties.getMockCSV() = "classpath:/first.csv", but its not assigned to proper variable in MockData class, which looks like this:

```
class MockData {

String CSV;

public MockData(
        String mockCSV) {
  // Following line is skipped in debug (and also in normal run)
    CSV = mockCSV;
  }
  // Do some stuff with CSV file
}
```

**Question:**

Why is the line in constructor for MockData with initialisation of CSV String

```
CSV = mockCSV;
```

skipped - not assigned and the code just continue (skip assignment), even if mockCSV has a correct value:

```
classpath:/first.csv
```

I think, that the problem is [initialisation order](http://farenda.com/java/java-initialization-order/), because I am using the value of CSV in method after the constructor and its null.

Comment: When is your MockData class constructed? My guess would be that it is happening at some point during the initialisation *before* the property has been set from the .yml file. It might be worth editing your question to include some context around where you call `new MockData(...)`.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question. I think that property was correctly read, because, if I go through in debug, the value of csvProperties.getMockCSV is set to: classpath:/first.csv.

Comment: You say "Following line is skipped" - that doesn't make any sense. Random lines won't just get skipped. What happens if you put some logging (just a `System.out.println(...)` will do) before and after that line. Do they get executed, or is the constructor never run. You still haven't shown any context around where you are calling that constructor.

Comment: The constructor never run. I am just surprised, that I am calling it through "return new MockData(csvProperties.getMockCSV());" and the assignment is not executed. I don't know what context do you mean? I already wrote whole Bean, from which is constructor called, what more should I write?

Comment: Show the code where you are calling the constructor. Are you certain that the code that calls the constructor is definitely being executed? Based on what you've shown, calling `new MockData(...)` will certainly populate the value. I think this question is getting very confusing, possibly because you're posting heavily modified versions of your code, and so important context is being lost. Maybe try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and posting that.

Comment: But the code is already there. Its first code block under Problem text, which is bolted. Yes, I am sure, that code is executed, because I can put brake point on that row and debug it. Ok, I will try it.

Comment: But that code says "Code for production solution - which works", so what's the problem? I think you need to spend some time rewriting your question to make it clear - try to put yourself in the position of someone who doesn't know your project, and explain only the relevant parts, with clear examples of what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Yes, it is comment, that in this part in my class is production branch of application which works as expected. But as I wrote, the question is not connected with that part of code at all - "In development mode we will try to read csv files" - and if you read further and observe @Profile annotation it is clear enough for me - I am in development profile, not production. I think, that question is clear, I also followed rules for questions. I expect, that at the end I have: CSV = classpath:/first.csv. This is why I am asking.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm starting to understand, what think you're saying is: Your class `WhereWeDecideWhichWayToGo` is a Spring `@Configuration` class, which defines a `@Bean`. If you remove the `@Profile` annotation (or set it to something else?) the application works correctly, BUT if you set it to "development", as you have it here, a new `MockData` object is created, but the value of the `CSV` field is not set (presumably it's `null`?). You've added a breakpoint inside the constructor of `MockData`, and another one inside the `createMockData()` method.

Comment: When you run the application, you get into the constructor every time, regardless of the profile that's set, and `csvProperties.getMockCSV()` always returns the value set in the .yml file, but in development mode, the value of `CSV` is not set. Is that right?

Comment: You got that absolutely right. Information about @Configuration is missing, that is my fault in description, Ill fix it. csvProperties.getMockCSV() is called only in development mode - because the production is reading the values from db. And yes, you are again right, that value of CSV is not set. I don't understand, why the is the assignment in constructor skipped? It is something with order of initialisation class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seemed to ignore my suggestion to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I've attempted to do so using the code from your question, and it works for me.

The code you've posted is obviously heavily edited from what you're actually doing, so I had to guess a few things, and there are also a few syntax errors in the examples you've posted, so I've attempted to infer what they really are in your code. Here's what I've done that works, along with notes about where I've guessed, hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

So, from the beginning, here's the class with `@SpringBootApplication`, presumably you have something like this somewhere in your codebase:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CSVExampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CSVExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration properties class. Note that you don't need it to be an `@Component`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("csv")
public class CSVProperties {
    private String firstCsv;

    public String getFirstCsv() {
        return firstCsv;
    }

    public void setFirstCsv(String firstCsv) {
        this.firstCsv = firstCsv;
    }
}
```

I called the property `firstCsv` to match the value from your `application.yml` file which is `first-csv`. It's interesting that in your code you seem to be referring to this property with `csvProperties.getMockCSV()`. I'm guessing that's just a typo in your question, because that will never work - the property name needs to match the key in your `application.yml` file.

Here's the configuration class. You haven't shown this anywhere in your examples, but presumably you have an equivalent somewhere. The important part is the `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, which must specify the class that has the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CSVProperties.class)
public class CSVExampleConfiguration {
    private final CSVProperties csvProperties;

    @Autowired
    public CSVExampleConfiguration(CSVProperties csvProperties) {
        this.csvProperties = csvProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!development")
    public MockData createProductionMockData() {
        return new MockData("production");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("development")
    public MockData createMockData() {
        return new MockData(csvProperties.getFirstCsv());
    }
}
```

It's also interesting that in your question you say you're creating the bean with a method that looks like `public CreateMockData createMockData() {`, but then you return a `MockData`. Again, I'm guessing this is a typo in your question, as it won't compile like this (unless `MockData` extends `CreateMockData`, but that seems odd).

I'm not sure how you're setting the production profile, but hopefully what I've done above is a reasonable equivalent - `@Profile("!development")` says "create this bean if the 'development' profile is not set"

My `application.yml` file is also slightly different from what you've posted in your question:

```
spring:
  profiles: development

csv:
  first-csv: classpath:/first.csv
```

Your example won't work at all, firstly because you're missing a `:` after `spring`, and secondly because you seem to have `csv` nested under `spring`, which isn't how you set the configuration properties - it needs to be at the root level as above. Again, I assume these are just typos in the question because you say the application starts (which it wouldn't with the missing `:`) and that you see the configuration property get set (which it wouldn't with `csv` nested under `spring`).

Finally, I tested all this with a simple controller. You haven't given any details about the rest of your application, but this is what I've done, which hopefully mimics your code:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    private final MockData mockData;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(MockData mockData) {
        this.mockData = mockData;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCsv() {
        return mockData.getCSV();
    }
}
```

So, then, with the application running and no profile set, if I visit `http://localhost:8080/foo` in a browser, I get the String "production" in the response, and if I restart the application, with a profile of "development", I get a response of "classpath:/first.csv".

I appreciate that this probably isn't the "just do this" answer that you might have hoped for, but I'd suggest you compare this to your code, and try to modify anything that differs. If you still can't get it to work, then there must be some other differences elsewhere in your application that are causing the problem. If you need more help, edit your question with the specifics that I've missed, but please try to post actual code (copy and pasted, not re-typed, to avoid introducing confusing typos).